# Custom close reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Once we get out of the private beta and have our own mods we will need to think about the custom close reasons that each site has.

This might be a good time to throw some ideas out there as to what we think should be our custom ones.

Try to keep each suggestion to one post, to allow voting on individual suggestions.

Most likely the mods will take the top few highest voted and use those so be liberal with your votes on what you think will help.

Suggestions for close reasons should help us enforce the boundaries of the site. This might be quite difficult to do this early in the beta, but at the same time early boundaries now should aid us in the long run!

Comment: From my experiences discussing close reasons on Physics (we even had a chat session extending to 4 hours!), it really helps if you have data to back it up -- Once you have a significant number of closed questions, you can start sorting them out and getting a custom reason in place. Till then, the default close reason will be there for use.

Answer (score 5):

- This question is about other space sciences (physics, weather, astronomy, etc), and does not directly pertain to space exploration as outlined in the FAQ.

Comment: This has the advantage of being more general purpose than Undo's individual close reasons (remember we only get three!)

Comment: Ah, shoot. I thought I had this covered. Now to think up what other topics... Wait! I've got one!

Comment: Remember, the FAQ is now kinda obsolete.

Comment: I believe the question migration options follow site's migrated questions statistics. For example, if we'll be migrating a lot of questions to [physics.se], then this option will appear among the "off-topic / belongs on anoter [SE] site" options. Moving to site's meta is probably a single default migration option, but others will be added as we make requests for migrations.

Answer (score 2):

I really miss the "too localized" option since the last update to the closing system. I'm not sure how often it would apply for questions posted on our website in particular, but since we have the "too broad" option, it feels only natural to also have the "too localized" one:

> **Too localized**:
>   This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only
>   relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an
>   extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to
>   the worldwide audience of the internet.

Answer (score 1):

This question appears to be off-topic because it is ...

> **requesting to provide information on behalf of a disassociated third party**. [Questions seeking product or service recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), or asking to provide legal advice of, about or on behalf of a third party we don't associate with, their products, services, and function are off-topic as they either become obsolete quickly, or our members cannot be expected to provide contracting or otherwise legally binding and meaningful information.

Comment: While this is good, I doubt that there will be sufficient questions to really make this a closed question reason.

Answer (score 0):

- This question is about weather, and not related to space exploration as defined in the FAQ.

Comment: Hmm, will we get enough questions frequently requiring this close reason to justify having it?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Thought I'd throw it out there, though.

Answer (score 0):

- This question is about physics, and is not related to space exploration as defined in the FAQ.

Comment: I like this one, we are going to have to define a border between us and physics and i can see this getting used alot

Comment: @RhysW Not necessarily. Sites are allowed to overlap wrt scope, and you just handle an overlap question where it is asked (unless the OP requests migration or the question doesn't get answers)

Comment: FWIW Physics.SE will be happy to accept migrations of physics-y questions

Answer (score -1):

- This question is specific to Earth, and not related to Space Exploration as outlined in the FAQ.

To catch [What, if any, plans have been made for handling events like a geomagnetic reversal?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-if-any-plans-have-been-made-for-handling-events-like-a-geomagnetic-revers)

Answer (score -1):

In light of new discoveries or abundance of available research work this question/answer is no longer appropriate for this site.