# Are transient questions on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This question received a close vote: *[When is Fēngyún-3C planned to launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1095/33)*

What do we do with transient questions?  Something similar may happen on Travel, if people are asking on how to travel to specific events.  What is our policy for this?

Answer (score 4):

Site self-evaluation tools have fairly recently received an overhaul, and among the most notable changes are the site-specific close reasons. These changes are explained in the Stack Exchange Blog [The War of the Closes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/):

> These site-specific reasons will also address situations previously
>   covered by “General Reference” and “Too Localized”. Those were the
>   least used and most misused reasons – moderator and team sampling
>   found a huge percentage of their application to be erroneous.

[The blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/) is a lot more detailed than the short excerpt above, so I recommend reading it in its entirety, although I'm quite certain you've noticed at least the majority of these changes yourself, too.

I personally miss the ["too localized"](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/203/49) reason to close questions, but appreciate we (Space Exploration) as an individual Stack Exchange community, need to agree on our own most common reasons to close questions, which questions are considered acceptable/appropriate/..., and which not, so we can enforce these rules with some conviction later on. If we won't be in agreement on such questions, we just won't be able to sustain a healthy and well defined community.

For the time being, we're still in the process of deciding over these ["custom close reasons"](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/64/49) that we're to eventually include in the list, meaning we haven't reached any consensus yet on any site-wide policy, and I can only provide my own opinion on the matter, which is fairly simple:

I agree with assessment of some reviewers that the question is too localized (it will only be relevant until the FY-3C is actually launched, which might be as soon as in a few days time, whenever the next launch window will be, if the unverified information is to be believed that [the satellite is ready for transport to the launch site](http://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=30407.msg1080622#msg1080622)). Due to the lack of any official information, the question could also be considered to solicit "primarily opinion-based" answers.

So - **TL;DR** - No policy yet, we need to decide on them first, and then include custom close reasons in our website's questions review options. My vote to close for this particular question mentioned is explained above. We also plan to [host launch related events](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/234/49) in our chat room - [The Pod Bay](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay), and questions or discussions like that certainly aren't off-topic there, they might even be appreciated by some of the regular dwellers there, myself included. Hope this helps, and please vote on proposals you consider agreeable in the ["custom close reasons"](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/64/49) thread, or even add your own suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Relevant Q&A from meta.SO:

- [Is it appropriate to ask questions of "temporary nature" here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113353/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-questions-of-temporary-nature-here)

Jeff Atwood said temporary Qs are better left for chat or twitter.

However, there are events which happen each year on Stack Exchange sites and which usually produce questions with great following. These are April Fool's Day questions.

They tend to generate a lot of answers and votes, but are deleted afterwards.
(I ain't kiddin'!)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have nothing against questions that [keep hanging for months unanswered until an answer becomes available](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120112/redstone-simulator-with-support-for-redstone-block). If the asker loses interest, they may delete the question, otherwise - they get the answer when they get it. Answers that are speculative or invalid simply shouldn't be accepted or upvoted.

Additionally, I'm not against [questions that become obsolete over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187414/clang-vs-gcc-which-produces-better-binaries), providing new answers are posted and selected by the asker as the "new valid". Even if that doesn't happen they provide a historical resource.