# Not enough options in the "Close question" interface

Tags: discussion

There are five options in the "Close question" interface:

- Duplicate of ...
- Off topic because ...
- Unclear what you're asking
- Too broad
- Primarily opinion-based

These options doesn't address the truly bad LMGTFY (let me google that for you) questions, those for which typing the title into google will readily yield the answer. A snarky sixth option would be "LMGTFY".

A less snarky option: "Too basic. This question is readily answered by asking a search engine."

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, and we've already started a thread asking our community for [Custom close reasons](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/64/49) that all our members can suggest and vote on and can be included by our moderators in the "off-topic" list once they gather sufficient support (with not many of our members active in Space Exploration Meta, I think we can settle for "at least 3 upvotes"?), so please add your suggestion there. We get to have up to three of such custom close reasons, so obviously there's a need to at least try to address as many of such possible close reasons in a compact and informative manner. Good writers needed! And please vote on already existing suggestions by your own preference and experience with what the site needs the most.

For these "LMGTFY" questions, I was thinking about something along the lines of a polite rejection pointing to our requirements for prior research, as described in our Help section [How do I ask a good question?](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (`[Ask]` shorthand for the text formatting) and that we're not trying to establish a community of domain experts only to answer non-challenging "curious about" or list questions that can perhaps be best dismissed with an easy to find, off-site link. But I lack sophistication and writing skills required, so please think of an agreeable and concise custom close reason text that would fit in a single comment (that's how much space we have for each of them). "List questions" would however likely warrant a new custom close reason, since there's only that much of text that can fit into them. But do try to capture as many that can fit *in the same basket* as you possibly can, given text length constraints.

And once you're done (or require input), post a link to your suggestion in our [main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay), asking for peer review and support of your notion. It's afteral for the benefit of the whole community.